# mysql replace character at position

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

If I have a variable in a stored procedure like this:
    declare str varchar(10);
    set str = 'ABCD';

How do I change a character in the string at an arbitrary position?
For example: in the procedure x is 3. I need to change str so it becomes
    str = 'AB*D';

This means that, as x is equals to 3, in the string, the character at the position 3, should be changed to '*'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with string manipulations:

```
select concat(left(str, 2), '*', substring(str, 4, 10))
```

Or, you can use the `insert()` function:

```
select insert(str, 3, 1, '*')
```

Comment: [Documentation on INSERT()](https://w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-insert-function.php) from w3resource.